# How to write a search query in mysql which matches columns from different tables and returns another column from the first table?

Tags: mysql

```
Table_1

Name    Age    City           Mobile
John S  40    New York        444444
Roy M   24    London          999999
Smith   30    Venice          444555

Table_2
Name      Age   Gender
John S    40      M
Sussane   28      F
```

What will be the query to match columns from Table_1 Name, Age and Table_2
Name,Age and return Mobile from Table_1.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It would be good if you mention what you tried and result of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select t1.mobile from table_1 t1, table_2 t2 where t1.name = t2.name and t1.age = t2.age
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *match columns* in

> What will be the query to match columns from Table_1 Name, Age and
>   Table_2 Name,Age and return Mobile from Table_1.

Your use case is not clear. I am assuming you want to exactly match Name and Age from each row of `table_2`. But what if there are multiple *John S*? Hence you should use a database key to identify the tuple(e.g. `user_id int auto_increment`).

You can use following query for the time-being:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.mobile
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_1 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
AND t1.age = t2.age
```